# fastify-jwt sign token with user ID payload

Tags: node.js, jwt, fastify, fastify-jwt

I'm making a simple sign-in function, that will return a token with the user's ID.

I've registered the `fastify-jwt` on the `fastify` instance with the key
and added user id in the call to the sign function.

Code **auth.js**

```
import Fastify from "fastify";
import fastifyJwt from "fastify-jwt";
import { users } from "../dummy-data/users.js";

const fastify = Fastify();
const SECRET_KEY = "secret";
fastify.register(fastifyJwt, { secret: SECRET_KEY });

......

const signIn = function (req, res) {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const foundUser = users.find(
    (user) => user.email === email && user.password === password
  );
  const { id } = foundUser;
  const accessToken = fastify.jwt.sign({ id }, SECRET_KEY);
  res.status(200).send({ accessToken });
}
```

but this does not work, it shows this error:

**"message": "Expected "options" to be a plain object."**

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Expected \"options\" to be a plain object."
}
```

anyone knows the correct approach?

Comment: How is `signIn` used? What is the expected result vs. actual result that makes you say "this does not work"?
(From here and according to the documentation, `.sign` method doesn't need the `SECRET_KEY` as a second argument, although indeed the linked JWT specification asks for it.)

Comment: I was confused, because JWT asks for Secret key. I found out `fastify-jwt` don't need SECRET_KEY when assigning.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to pass the SECRET_KEY when signing

```
const accessToken = fastify.jwt.sign({ id });
```

because it is already passed to the jwt-plugin when it is registered:

```
fastify.register(fastifyJwt, { secret: SECRET_KEY });
```